# cant seem to access array in for loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so im trying to make a for loop in c# with a list and array that are both from another script and cant seem to make out the 2nd for loop.
the loop with the list works but cant do the one with the array

code from the original script

```
public class SceneImages : ScriptableObject
{
    public List<SceneImage> artWork;
}

[Serializable]
    public struct SceneImage
    {
        public string[] sceneName;
        public Sprite loadingSprite;
    }
```

script that i coudldnt create

```
for(int i=0; i < SceneImage.sceneName.Length; i++) { }
```

Comment: where do you want to loop the images? Is this loop inside the `SceneImages`-class or somewhere else?

Comment: iterating over `SceneImage.sceneName` is wrong. `SceneImage` is a type and has no static member `sceneName`. You need to create an instance.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an instance of a SceneImage to access its values.
In this case it could be

```cs
SceneImage image = new SceneImage();
image.sceneName = new string[]{"scene name"};
image.loadingSprite = /* sprite value*/;
for(int i=0; i < image.sceneName.Length; i++) { }
```